# Change figure numbering for appendix

Tags: floats, numbering, appendices

I want to "reset" the figure counting in my document when the appendix starts, and follow a different pattern than 1, 2, 3... Specifically, I want figures in the appendix to start with A.1, A.2 onward, instead of continuing on from the main document. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,dblfloatfix}


\usepackage{titlesec}% Allows customization of titles
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering{\Roman{section}.}}{}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Problem description}
Blah blah
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering 
    \includegraphics{decon}
    \caption{Call this figure 1.}
\label{fig1} 
\end{figure}
\appendix
\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering 
    \includegraphics{decon}
    \caption{Call this figure A.1.}
\label{figa1} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering 
    \includegraphics{decon}
    \caption{Call this figure A.2.}
\label{figa2} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Redefine `\thefigure` when your appendices start, and set the figure counter to zero at the beginning of each appendix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}
\appendix
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}    
\section{A nice appendix}
\setcounter{figure}{0}    
\begin{figure}
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is a figure in appendix A}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this still requires resetting the figure counter with `\setcounter{figure}{0}` for each section of the Appendix.

Comment: This breaks hyperref too.

Comment: In my environment, where I used \part{Appendix} to group my appendixes as chapters, the proposed solution yields the format 'A.0.1' for instance. Hence I turned it to
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}, now working the same as above.

Answer (score 64):

You can use the [`chngcntr` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) which includes the command `\counterwithin`.

Using this as `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` changes the figure numbering from that point on so that the section number is included and resets the numbering of figures at the beginning each subsequent section.  An example is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Problem description}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering Figure
  \caption{Call this figure 1.}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering Figure
  \caption{Call this figure A.1.}
  \label{figa1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering Figure
  \caption{Call this figure A.2.}
  \label{figa2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: To make this work for tables, you need to also put `\counterwithin{table}{section}`.

Comment: With this solution, `hyperref` links properly to the appendix figure (with the accepted solution,  `hyperref` links to Figure 1 in stead of Figure A.1, etc).

Comment: @midobal are hyperref links the same thing here as cref [from the cleveref package] links? 'Cause these work correctly for me with the accepted solution.

Comment: Starts the Appendix and figures with '.1' instead of 'A' for me...

Comment: @Archie That sounds like you are using a class such as `report` or `book` where the top level units are chapters and/or you have used `\section*`.  Adjust the `\counterwithin` command to your set-up.  If you have problems with that, please post a new question.

Comment: True, it's part of a `book`. How should I change the command, to `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}`?

Comment: @Archie Yes, that would be the first thing to try.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple appendix sections, but have all figures appear throughout the sections and have the prefix Figure A.#?

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor I think you should ask a new question, giving more details of what you wish.

Comment: @AndrewSwann how would you have the "A"-prefix in the appendix figures but not in the Appendix section heading ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624131/244928

Comment: @SamuelSaari The easiest way would be to use `\section*` for the heading plus `\refstepcounter{section}` just after the heading.  If you need a contents entry for the heading, you can add that with `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Figures}`

Answer (score 53):

A simple way to prepend an A to your appendix figures and to have the counter reset is to paste the following two lines before your first figure of the appendix.

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
```

as illustrated [here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/Customizing_numbering_pages.html).

Comment: And, obviously, `\renewcommand{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}` and `\setcounter{table}{0}` (note that I prefer using the dot in the middle, e.g. A.1.. just to say, this solution is no less general than the other twos)

Comment: This was the best solution for me, because references still work, the chapter number of the appendix is not affected and the figure numbering is customizable.

Answer (score 6):

I added 
- `hbAppendixPrefix` to change prefix easily 
- equation numbering, too

```
\newcommand{\hbAppendixPrefix}{A}
%
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\hbAppendixPrefix\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\hbAppendixPrefix\arabic{table}} 
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\hbAppendixPrefix\arabic{equation}} 
\setcounter{equation}{0}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution for everything which manages both figures and tables in appendix

```
\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

Comment: This doesn't work without the proper import

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet due to low rep but I want to add a note that expands on the answer by @ian-thompson

If you want to add a prefix to all figures and tables in the appendix regardless of which section of the appendix it's in, you can use the code below. Ian's answer generates Figure A.1, A.2 etc in the first section of an appendix but then Figure B.1, B.2 in the next section. If you want static prefix, we remove "\thesection" from the renewcommand line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}
\appendix


% Change figure labelling
\renewcommand\thefigure{PrefixTextHere.\arabic{figure}}    
\setcounter{figure}{0}  

% Change table labelling
\renewcommand\thetable{PrefixTextHere.\arabic{figure}}    
\setcounter{table}{0}    

\begin{figure}
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is a figure in appendix A}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In relation to the OP's request the relevant lines to graft into the above would be:

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{A.\arabic{figure}}    
\renewcommand\thefigure{A.\arabic{figure}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't break `hyperref` and doesn't require additional packages is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Text.

\begin{figure}
  \centering Figure.
  \caption{Main text figure.}
  \label{fig:one}
\end{figure}

This links to a figure in the main text: Fig.~\ref{fig:one}. But this links to a figure in the appendix: Fig.~\ref{fig:Aone}.

\cleardoublepage % just to show that the cross-references go to different places

\appendix

\counterwithin*{figure}{part}

\stepcounter{part}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}

This is the Appendix.

\begin{figure}
  \centering Appendix Figure.
  \caption{A figure in the Appendix.}
  \label{fig:Aone}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```