# Numbering of tables and figures after appendix

Tags: appendices

I am submitting a revision of my paper and I have to put my tables and figures at the end of manuscript. The problem is that I have an appendix before my figures and table which cause the numbering to be assigned as the appendix format:
Figure A.1, Figure A.2,....

Does anyone has encountered the same situation before? Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Try the `appendices` environment, from the  `appendix` package, and put your tables and figures after the end of the  environment.

Comment: I generally use tables/figures at their normal places and then use `endfloat` package to add them at the end of the paper. If you are using the same and still having a problem, post a MWE; so that it is easy to guess the problem/workaround.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85779/107114), you can add

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
```

to the preamble of your document, and

```
\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

before floats with new naming format.