# how to number the images using letters and numbers

Tags: floats, numbering

I have 3 images and i want to number the images as follows: 1.a, 1.b, 1.c
to solve this problem i referred to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85776/change-figure-numbering-for-appendix) but it is not exactly what i want, the link shows how to number the images as follows: A.1, A.2, A.3 while i want it other way around something like 1.a, 1.b,1.c

please let me know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `subfigure` environment from `subcaption`, and redefine `\thesubcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure.\alph{subfigure}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{plain}{#2}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{AliceSteadman}
        \caption{\label{fig:Alice1}}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{AliceSteadman}
        \caption{\label{fig:Alice2}}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{AliceSteadman}
        \caption{\label{fig:Alice3}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:Alice}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried ur answer but i getting this error: ! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation

Comment: In cooperation with what? You're probably loding the obsolete package `subfigure`, or `subfig`?

Comment: i am using \usepackage{subfig} and i need it because i have the following :\begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
    
    \subfloat[Without EKF]{{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{4_no_EKF_marked} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[With EKF]{{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{4_EKF_marked} }}%
    
    \caption{Comparison between the vehicle position derived from the GNSS sensor and the vehicle position derived from EKF filter}%
    \label{fig:Accuracy of Positioning}
\end{figure}

Comment: But you also can do that with the `subfigure` environment.