# Appendix prefixes in figure names, but not in section heading

Tags: floats, numbering, titles, appendices, section-titles

I would like to have an `A` prefix in the appendix figures, but not in the section heading – *and include the Appendix in the table of contents.*

[image]

A MWE inspired be [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85779/244928)  answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % remove numbers from section headings

%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{duck}
    \label{fig:duck}
\end{figure}

\blindtext


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % add numbers to section headings, needed for prefix in the figures
\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\section{Appendix}\label{appendix}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Image in Appendix}
    \label{fig:image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

P.S. See also a related question in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624143/244928) (these were originally in the same post, but decided to seperate them for clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using KOMA class, just use `\addsec{}`

MVE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % remove numbers from section headings

%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{Section 1}
    
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{duck}
        \label{fig:duck}
    \end{figure}
    
    \blindtext
    
    
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % add numbers to section headings, needed for prefix in the figures
    \appendix
    \counterwithin{figure}{section}
    \stepcounter{section}
    \addsec{Appendix}
    
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Image in Appendix}
        \label{fig:image}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

An alternative non-KOMA class way (from a comment thread of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85779/244928) answer by [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann) ):

"The easiest way would be to use `\section*` for the heading plus `\refstepcounter{section}` just after the heading. If you need a contents entry for the heading, you can add that with `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Figures}`"