# Appendix prefixes in page numbers, but not in page count

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, appendices, lastpage, pageslts

I would like to have an `A` prefix in appendix page numbering, but not in appendix page count.

[image: No prefix in page count]

A MWE inspired be [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57809/244928)  answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{pageslts} % mixes up the page numbering in the appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic} % page count in the body


%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\textbf{Number of pages:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \pageref{lastpage} pages in the body
    \item \pageref{applastpage} pages in appendix
\end{itemize}


\section{Section 2}

\Blindtext

\label{lastpage} % page count

\clearpage
\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % page count
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A.\arabic{page}} % adds prefix to page numbering

\section{Appendix}\label{appendix}

\blindtext 

\label{applastpage} % page count
\end{document}
```

P.S. See also a related question in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624131/244928) (these were originally in the same post, but decided to differentiate them for clarity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  First, you can use `\getpagerefnumber` and `\StrBehind` to remove `A.` etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{pageslts} % mixes up the page numbering in the appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic} % page count in the body

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xstring}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \edef\lastpageA{\getpagerefnumber{applastpage}}%
  \StrBehind{\lastpageA}{.}[\lastpageB]%
}

%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\textbf{Number of pages:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \pageref{lastpage} pages in the body
    \item {\lastpageB} pages in appendix
\end{itemize}


\section{Section 2}

\Blindtext

\label{lastpage} % page count

\clearpage
\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % page count
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A.\arabic{page}} % adds prefix to page numbering

\section{Appendix}\label{appendix}

\blindtext 

\label{applastpage} % page count
\end{document}
```

---

The second way is to save `\arabic{page}` in the `\label` (using `\ref`, not `\pageref`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{pageslts} % mixes up the page numbering in the appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic} % page count in the body

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\savepage}[1]{% #1 = label name for page counter
  \edef\@currentlabel{\arabic{page}}%
  \label{#1}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\textbf{Number of pages:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \ref{lastpage} pages in the body
    \item \ref{applastpage} pages in appendix
\end{itemize}


\section{Section 2}

\Blindtext

\savepage{lastpage} % page count

\clearpage
\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % page count
\renewcommand{\thepage}{A.\arabic{page}} % adds prefix to page numbering

\section{Appendix}\label{appendix}

\blindtext 

\savepage{applastpage} % page count
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found the second way especially straightforward. Since I am using ```hyperref```, I just added and asterisk to disable the links (```\ref*{lastpage}```)